# "Fixing" large angles in C

Tags: c

I need to be able to compare angles that are multiples of 45 in C (input always in degrees).

I've written the code for basic angles 0,45,90,135,180...
But I can also get large angles like 2070 which is the same as 90.

How do I do it? (Sorry if it's a terribly simple question, I'm just getting into this)

So far, I've tried converting the angle to radians and using the sine function. But the problem is that I can't compare them using the `==` operator.

This is the only way I've learned to compare values in C so far

```
double direction;
scanf("%d", &direction);

int x = sin(direction * 0.0174533);
//Wanted to use the == operator, so I thought I'd assign the sin to an int.

if (x == 1) {
    someInstruction();
}
```

The problem is that when I make it into an int, the value becomes 0 and not 1.

Comment: is your input in degrees? if so you just have to do "direction % 45 == 0". if the statement is true the angle is a multiple of 45.

Comment: Please note that `scanf("%d", &direction);` has undefined behavior (the compiler should have warned you), given that `direction` is declared as `double`, but you are using the wrong format specifier (`%d` requires an `int`). You should either use an `int` (which will greatly simplify your task) or the correct format specifier (`%lf`) in `scanf`. If you keep the `double` type, take a look at [`fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod).

Comment: Do not write `0.0174533` in code. Use `M_PI/180`. The former puzzles readers. The latter shows intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the sine of the angle if you like to compare them. Actually it will give you headaches because exact equality of floating point values has its own problem. I'm not going deeper in it, if you're interested the research is left as an exercise for you.

Instead I'd like to introduce the "[modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)" operator to you. This operator does a integer division and returns the remainder. In C and derived languages the operator is "%".

So you let the user input the angle as integer and calculate the remainder of the division by 360: `int remainder = input % 360;`

Examples:

```
input remainder
   0    0
 135  135
2070  270
3645   45
```

Answer (score 0):

when you convert `double` to `int` it truncate the number to the closest `int` in the case of `sin` it's either -1/0/1.

*dummy example:*

```
double x_d =1.2;
int x_i = x_d
```

will result in `x_i=1`

You need to keep it as `double` or even `float` so it will keep the output of the `sin` and you can do the testing you desire.

As *Arya11* mentioned a more elegant way to approach the issue is using the modulo operator `%` which you need to only check if the `direction` is a multiple of the desired angle.